# Failing to install dependencies for a custom project

Tags: python, setuptools, install-requires

So I am having a project that is meant to be able to be distributed and it is dependent on some other pip-installable modules. That is how `setup.py` looks like:

```
import setuptools
from rss_reader.rss_reader import VERSION

setuptools.setup(name='whatever',
      version=VERSION[1:],
      description='RSS-feed reader',
      long_description='Pure Python command line RSS-feed reader ',
      packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
      classifiers=["Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
                   "Operating System :: OS Independent"],
      python_requires='>=3.5',
      entry_points={'console_scripts': ['rssreader=rss_reader.rss_reader:main']},
      install_requires=['bs4',
                        'feedparser',
                        'html5lib',
                        'jsonpickle',
                        'requests'])
```

In order to make sure everything works just fine I tried to install the package in a Docker container, and `pip install .` causes a `ModuleNotFound Error`. By installing the dependencies manually the problem gets solved, so I'm pretty sure `install_requires` is what the problem is. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I comment out this import `from rss_reader.rss_reader import VERSION` and add version manually it works for me. Can you kindly share error logs if possible.

Answer (score 0):

So what turned out to be the answer is making another file with VERSION and importing exactly this variable; `rss_reader.rss_reader` looks like this:

```
...
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
...
VERSION='v0.3'
...
```

So it tries to import BeautifulSoup before assigning version and, therefore, before the actual install